# Not able to download required components(ANDROID STUDIO)

Tags: android-studio

I am not able to download required components for android studio.
Every time I click download remaining components it shows:

> ERROR:time out.

Further explanation is given by image.

Comment: What image do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put a Image there but normally every update & every downloadable feature could be installed manuel. So you should try to find the Updatepackage or whatever you try to install and do it alone / manuel.